# android something wrong with 9 patch in ListView

Tags: android

I use ImageView  for listview item , but there is a problem when UI rendering , and code snippets :

```
int placeholder = R.drawable.placeholder;//placeholder.9.png in res/drawable-xxhdpi folder

img.setImageResource(placeholder);

img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

*Placeholder image:*

[image: this placeholder image]

*Screen capture image:*

[image: this screen capture image]

the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:xiaozhi="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/channel_list_item_fullimage_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/xz_fragment_item_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="?attr/news_main_text_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <com.inveno.xiaozhi.widget.IRatioImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_fullimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="?attr/img_alpha"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        xiaozhi:ratio="2.0"/>

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        layout="@layout/item_viewstub_swith_title_rss" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:background="?attr/xz_fragment_divider_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

is someone meet it and hava some suggestion to fix the problem ?

Comment: Add the layout file for that.

Comment: I've added the layout file

Answer (score 0):

you should place the  **placeholder.9.png** in the **res/drawable** folder

and set ImageView resource by calling the id from the drawable folder path

```
Resources resources = getResources();
img.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder.9));
```

Comment: the placeholder.9.png is in the res/drawable-xxhdpi folder

Comment: try this updated the code, if not then check the view is initiaiized correctly

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to fix the problem:

just edit the lines for the stretchable patches.

at top stretchable patchs: drawing 1px to 3px On the far left,drawing 1px to 3px on the far right

at left stretchable patchs: drawing 1px to 3px On the top left,drawing 1px to 3px on the bottom right